# Node.js on Azure - Adding default documents & mime types

Tags: node.js, azure

I deployed a node.js site to Azure and everything was working great, except I noticed that markdown (`.md`) files we're being served up. Found another solution where I needed to add a `web.config` to my site to white list that extension, but now the default documents for the site (`events.html`) are no longer being respected.

How do you tell in the `web.config` for a node.js site running on azure to "add this mime type, but do everything else the same way you were doing it"?

Here's my `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>         
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".md" mimeType="text/x-markdown" />
    </staticContent>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That's the pretty standard web.config I use, too... is it just a particular set of paths that this no longer works with (`*.html` it sounds like)?

Comment: No, it works if you go to /events.html, but if you don't specify the URL, it doesn't use the events.html file as the default file when you browse the directory. This did work before I added the web.config. I didn't think it would overwrite what I specified in the Azure config for the default doc... guessing I need to specify it here using the web.config: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/defaultdocument

Comment: @AndrewConnell if defaultDocument fixed it for you, just supply your own answer!